# Selecting between text with a newline spanning

Tags: notepad++, regex

I have the following (tab separated with an additional tab before the new line)

```
Where are we?   Missä me olemme?    
We are at school.   Olemme koulussa.    
We are having class / a lesson. Meillä on opetusta.
```

and I want to get (minus the tab before the newline)

```
Missä me olemme?
Olemme koulussa.
Meillä on opetusta.
```

I'm currently using

```
\n(.*?)\t
```

But this doesn't remove the tab before the new line.

I tried

```
\t\n(.*?)\t
```

But that doesn't work for some reason. How do I fix this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `^.+?\t(.+?)\t`
- Replace with: `$1`
- *check Wrap around*
- *check Regular expression*
- *DO NOT CHECK `. matches newline`*
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
^       : beginning of line
.+?     : 1 or more any character, not greedy
\t      : a TAB
(.+?)   : group 1, 1 or more any character, not greedy
\t      : a TAB
```

**Replacement:**

```
$1          : content of group 1 (i.e. what is inbetween TABs)
```

**Result for given example:**

```
Missä me olemme?
Olemme koulussa.
Meillä on opetusta.
```

Comment: Thanks, I never knew about the content of group match. Now I do ;)

Comment: @user126440: You're welcome, glad it helps.